# Apollo-codegen introspection throws error

Tags: schema, apollo, introspection

I have been working with apollo-codegen to introspect my schema in a proyect without problem and from one moment to other it started showing this error.

**Command:**

```
apollo-codegen introspect-schema https://localhost:4000/graphql --insecure --output schema.json
```

**Error**

```
error: Errors in introspection query result: [object Object]
```

I have tried in a version of the proyect i haven´t changed where it worked fine but know it throws that error too.

Also tried deleting the package and installig it again without success.

I have seen that apollo has apollo Cli now but the -k flag is not working and i cant introspect my server with selfsigned certificates.

Does some one have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to migrate to Apollo CLI with not success due to the imposibility to introspect a self-signed certified endpoint I decided to try again with apollo-codegen and I found out that the problem was my backend blocking the process. I fixed it passing to the introspec-schema command a header to pass over the backend control.

The real problema here was that the message error was very unclear so the debuging was difficult.

This package is deprecated now so it won`t be improved but this explanation could help someone still using it.